# Kafka Producer - org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer could not be found

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-karaf, spark-streaming-kafka

I have creating a simple Kafka Producer & Consumer.I am using kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0. Here is my Producer code.

```
public class KafkaProducerTest {
public static String topicName = "test-topic-2";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("acks", "all");
    props.put("retries", 0);
    props.put("batch.size", 16384);
    props.put("linger.ms", 1);
    props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
    props.put("key.serializer",
            StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put("value.serializer",
            StringSerializer.class.getName());

    Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer(props);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(
                topicName, Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i));
        System.out.println(producerRecord);
        producer.send(producerRecord);
    }

    producer.close();
}

}
```

While starting the bundle I a facing the below error:

```
2016-05-20 09:44:57,792 | ERROR | nsole user karaf | ShellUtil                        | 44 - org.apache.karaf.shell.core - 4.0.3 | Exception caught while executing command
org.apache.karaf.shell.support.MultiException: Error executing command on bundles:
    Error starting bundle162: Activator start error in bundle NewKafkaArtifact [162].
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.support.MultiException.throwIf(MultiException.java:61)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:69)[24:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.execute(BundlesCommand.java:54)[24:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.action.command.ActionCommand.execute(ActionCommand.java:83)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:67)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:87)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:480)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:406)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:182)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:119)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:94)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.ConsoleSessionImpl.run(ConsoleSessionImpl.java:270)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error starting bundle162: Activator start error in bundle NewKafkaArtifact [162].
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:66)[24:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.3]
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle NewKafkaArtifact [162].
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2276)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2144)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.Start.executeOnBundle(Start.java:38)[24:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:64)[24:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.3]
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer for configuration key.serializer: Class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer could not be found.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:255)[141:kafka-examples:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:145)[141:kafka-examples:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:49)[141:kafka-examples:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:56)[141:kafka-examples:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.java:317)[141:kafka-examples:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:181)[141:kafka-examples:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies]
    at com.NewKafka.NewKafkaArtifact.KafkaProducerTest.main(KafkaProducerTest.java:25)[162:NewKafkaArtifact:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.NewKafka.NewKafkaArtifact.StartKafka.start(StartKafka.java:11)[162:NewKafkaArtifact:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:697)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2226)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
    ... 16 more
```

I have tried setting the `key.serializer` and `value.serializer` like below:

```
props.put("key.serializer",StringSerializer.class.getName());
props.put("value.serializer",StringSerializer.class.getName());
```

Also like, But still getting the same error. What is I am doing wrong here.

```
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

Comment: hey @Sanjeev try using   props.put("key.serializer", 
         "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
  props.put("value.serializer", 
         "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"); I have posted full example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its issue with the version you are using.
It was also suggested to version 0.8.2.2_1.
Suggest you to adjust the version of kafka you are using and give a try.
code wise, I cross checked many code samples in kafka dev list and seems like you have written in right way.

i.e `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);`

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Updating the kafka version to 0.8.2.2_1 or to latest didn't work. Adding the below line before setting the properties did the trick.                                 Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);

Comment: @ram : will you please help to answer this , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74888635/spring-kafka-msk-unable-to-find-loginmodule-class

Answer (score 12):

I find the reason by reading the kafka client source code.

kafka client use `Class.forName(trimmed, true, Utils.getContextOrKafkaClassLoader())` to get the Class object, and the create the instance, the key point is the classLoader, which is specified by the last param, the implementation of method `Utils.getContextOrKafkaClassLoader()` is

```
public static ClassLoader getContextOrKafkaClassLoader() {
    ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    if (cl == null)
        return getKafkaClassLoader();
    else
        return cl;
}
```

so, by default, the Class object of `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer` is load by the applicationClassLoader, if your target class is not loaded by the applicationClassLoader, this problem will happend !

to solve the problem, simply set the ContextClassLoader of current thread to null before new KafkaProducer instance like this

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer(props);
```

hope my answer can let you know what happend .

Comment: If I add this Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null); I get problem in registering other bean.

Comment: @Sheel You might save current thread context classloader in a variable, set context class loader for current thread to null, create kafka producer and then restore mentioned class loader  from the variable. There is an example: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/53653490/1673775](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53653490/1673775). This is still workaround. You might consider using other version of kafka or try to find out what is going on with classloading in your app if you need a true solution.

Comment: Thanks buddy, actually I was importing wrong file.This issue is solved.Now struggling with another one,Let you know.

Comment: @Kai , will you please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74888635/spring-kafka-msk-unable-to-find-loginmodule-class

Answer (score 6):

The issue appears to be with the class loader, as @Ram Ghadiyaram indicated in his answer.  In order to get this working with kafka-clients 2.x, I had to do the following:

```
public Producer<String, String> createProducer() {
            ClassLoader original = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
        BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
    ... etc ...

    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(original);
    return producer;

}
```

This allows the system to continue loading additional classes with the original classloader.  This was needed in Wildfly/JBoss (the specific app I'm working with is Keycloak).

Comment: will you please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74888635/spring-kafka-msk-unable-to-find-loginmodule-class

Answer (score 4):

try using these props instead of yours props.

```
  props.put("key.serializer", 
         "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

  props.put("value.serializer", 
         "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

Here is full Kafka Producer Example:-

```
import java.util.Properties; 
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;    
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
public class FxDateProducer {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

      if(args.length == 0){
         System.out.println("Enter topic name”);
         return;
      }

      String topicName = args[0].toString(); 
      Properties props = new Properties();

      //Assign localhost id
      props.put("bootstrap.servers", “localhost:9092");

      //Set acknowledgements for producer requests.      
      props.put("acks", “all");

      //If the request fails, the producer can automatically retry,
      props.put("retries", 0);

      //Specify buffer size in config
      props.put("batch.size", 16384);

      //Reduce the no of requests less than 0   
      props.put("linger.ms", 1);

      //The buffer.memory controls the total amount of memory available to the producer for buffering.   
      props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);

      props.put("key.serializer", 
         "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

      props.put("value.serializer", 
         "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

      Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer
         <String, String>(props);

      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName, 
            Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)));
               System.out.println(“Message sent successfully”);
               producer.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently i found the solution. Setting the Thead Context loader to null resolved the issue for me. Thanks.

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer(props);
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of kafka-version issue. Make sure, you use the correct kafka version. The version that I used is 'kafka_2.12-1.0.1'

But try using below properties in your code .This fixed my issue.

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

Earlier I was using below properties which was causing the issue.

```
//props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Stringserializer");
//props.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Stringserializer");
```