# Kafka Java Client: ClassLoader doesn't find SASL/Scram Login Class

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

Building an **SPI** to push events into **Kafka**, to get deployed as an **EAR** inside **Keycloak 6.0.1**, which uses the **WildFly** Server, packaged in a **Docker** image based on `jboss/keycloak:6.0.1`.

I ran into: [Kafka Producer - org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363119/kafka-producer-org-apache-kafka-common-serialization-stringserializer-could-no)

So I applied the suggested solution of setting `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);`.

This seems to work fine for my local Kafka on port 9092, without authentication. As soon as I authenticate as described [here](https://github.com/CloudKarafka/java-kafka-example/blob/master/src/main/java/KafkaExample.java):

```java
String jaasTemplate = "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"%s\" password=\"%s\";";
String jaasCfg = String.format(jaasTemplate, username, password);

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("sasl.jaas.config", jaasCfg);
// ...
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);
KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
```

I run into the error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class: org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:160)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:67)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.newSender(KafkaProducer.java:441)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:422)
```

I suspect that this is caused by setting the ClassLoader to `null`, but I'm not certain.

The JAAS string mentions this `org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule`. I tried not using JAAS but instead plain username + password like so:

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("sasl.username", username);
props.put("sasl.password", password);
// ...
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);
KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
```

But that also resulted in an Exception, just mentioning a different Class could not be located:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class: org.jboss.as.security.remoting.RemotingLoginModule
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:160)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:67)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.newSender(KafkaProducer.java:441)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:422)
```

How can I make it, that the `org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule` is found? Thanks!

Comment: Do you also set `sasl.mechanism` and `security.protocol`
 as described here https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_scram.html#clients ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning: ugly hack!

Just before you create the KafkaProducer, set the context classloader shown bellow:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

Comment: This is the answer! don't set ContextClassLoader to null. Do this instead.