# Read kafka Event

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using below command to read kafka event.

```
 bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic kafka-demo --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

But it is opening kafka-console-consumer.sh in noteped instead of printing the kafka event message.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally mean Windows Notepad app, then Shell files are meant for UNIX systems, not Windows.

Use `bin\windows` Batch scripts instead

Comment: Hi, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57574901/kafka-java-client-classloader-doesnt-find-sasl-scram-login-class 
For this question, I could not able to find the proper fix. Could you please help with this? The answer is working but I believe that is not a proper fix.

Comment: Please don't hijack posts with unrelated issues. Feel free to follow this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76711363/kafkaexception-jdk-internal-loader-classloaders-can-t-find-org-apache-kafka-com