# KafkaException: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders can’t find org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModule found for org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:184)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:81)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:105)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.newSender(KafkaProducer.java:447)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:428)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModule found for org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:739)
```

I am calling `kafkaTemplate.send` asynchronously, completed by a task running with a customized `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

- Spring Boot version : 2.6.12
- Java version : 17
- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:7.2.1
- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.3.1
- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.9.1

Furthermore, when the thread context class loader is set to `org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader` explicitly, this is working fine.

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

How can I make it work without this explicit change? Appreciate if someone help me with this. TIA