# unable to find LoginModule class: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule when the springboot app is run on docker container

Tags: java, apache-kafka

i have a spring boot application using `spring-kafka` dependency to publish a message to kafka,
the kafka config uses the standard kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config for authentication to the kafka server, the application is able to run and publish the message when run on intelliJ IDEA but same code when i run using a docker-compose by building a container it fails to publish a message with the below logs.

> org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:434) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
> |   at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:287) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]

> Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule
> | at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:794) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> |   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> |   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> |   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> |   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> |   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> |   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> |   at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.AbstractLogin.login(AbstractLogin.java:60) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
> |   at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.(LoginManager.java:62) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
> |   at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:105) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
> |   at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:158) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]

Comment: Sounds like you didn't create a fat jar that includes the Kafka dependencies... Please show your dockerfile and build file (maven/Gradle)

Comment: in the dockerfile i am copying a war generated by the mvn clean install to the tomcat base image

Comment: I'm not familiar with war files, but spring has an embedded tomcat server, so you only need a jar file and the openjdk base image. Regardless, that doesn't answer the question - you need to package the Kafka dependencies into that file

Comment: Refer https://www.baeldung.com/deployable-fat-jar-spring-boot

Answer (score 3):

A bit late on this issue, I hope someone will find this useful.

The dependencies might be there. However, you can "force" the classloader to pick up the correct classes by invoking:

```
final ClassLoader currentClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

try {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(KafkaProducer.class.getClassLoader());
    // PRODUCER INVOCATION HERE
} finally {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(currentClassLoader);
}
```

This is similar to the question asked here: [Kafka Producer - org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363119/kafka-producer-org-apache-kafka-common-serialization-stringserializer-could-no)

Comment: will you please help to answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74888635/spring-kafka-msk-unable-to-find-loginmodule-class