# Spring Kafka MSK : Unable to find LoginModule class:

Tags: spring-kafka, aws-msk

I am trying to connect to AWS MSK using SASL protocol in a spring boot project. I am using spring-kafka to connect. The error I am getting is

> org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: javax.security.auth.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class:software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule

Here are my producer config details. I am using the sample program as producer

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String,String> getProducerFactoryAWS()
{

Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);
Map<String,Object> configProps =  new HashMap<>();

configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"XXXX.XXXXX");
configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class);
configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class);
configProps.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG,"SASL_SSL");
configProps.put(Saslconfigs.SASL_MECHANISM,"AWS_MSK_IAM");
configProps.put(Saslconfigs.SASL_CLIENT_CALLBACK_HANDLER_CLASS,"com.xxxx.cto.jade.aws.sdk1.msk.JadeMskClientCallbackHandler");
configProps.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG,"software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required XXXXXXXX");

return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}
```

few dependencies from pom.xml are as below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>software.amazon.msk</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-msk-iam-auth</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I am not able to copy paste entire code due to security concerns. I have gone through [unable to find LoginModule class: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule when the springboot app is run on docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66261214/unable-to-find-loginmodule-class-org-apache-kafka-common-security-plain-plainlo) but not able to understand where to put that code as I am not creating producer by calling constructor in my code.
I tried setting below line but still same error.

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem is solved after putting below line

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassloader());
```

instead of

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);
```