# Unable to find LoginModule PlainLoginModule

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

For an existing application Im working on adding a functionality for being able to produce information on to a Kafka-topic.
The application is based on SpringBoot:3.0.1 together with Java 17 and built using Gradle:7.6. To enable the kafka-functionality Ive also added Spring-kafka:3.0.1 as a dependency.

The code is pretty simple. I declare a configuration

```
public ProducerFactory<String, DeltaLogMessage> producerFactory() {
    final ClassLoader currentClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    // TRY AS SUGGESTED IN https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66261214/unable-to-find-loginmodule-class-org-apache-kafka-common-security-plain-plainlo
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(KafkaProducer.class.getClassLoader());

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(
                Map.of(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress,
                        ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class,
                        ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class,
                        CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, security_protocol,
                        SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, sasl_mechanism,
                        SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, String.format("%s required username=\"%s\" " + "password=\"%s\";", PlainLoginModule.class.getName(), "", ""),
                        "ssl.truststore.location", truststore_location,
                        "ssl.truststore.password", truststore_password
                ));

    } finally {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(currentClassLoader);
    }
}
```

and then I use it like

```
kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC_NAME, msg)
```

Here is the problem.
While running the application through IntelliJ it works like a charm. However, when packaging into a fat-jar and run using something like

> java -jar fatjar.jar

I get the error that the Jaas-moduel PlainLoginModule is missing and cant be loaded (ClassNotFoundException) resulting in LoginException.

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException:
> javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModule found for
> org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:184)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.3.1.jar!/:na]   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:192)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.3.1.jar!/:na]   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:81)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.3.1.jar!/:na]   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:105)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.3.1.jar!/:na]   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.newSender(KafkaProducer.java:514)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.3.1.jar!/:na]   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:457)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.3.1.jar!/:na]   ... 17 common frames omitted Caused
> by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModule found for
> org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule   at
> java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:739)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:679)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:677)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:677)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.AbstractLogin.login(AbstractLogin.java:60)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.3.1.jar!/:na]   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.(LoginManager.java:62)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.3.1.jar!/:na]   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:105)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.3.1.jar!/:na]   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:170)
> ~[kafka-clients-3.3.1.jar!/:na]   ... 22 common frames omitted

I can see that the produced jar-file contains the required dependency (kafka-clients:3.3.1).

> jar tvf build/libs/mitaka-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  | grep kafka
> BOOT-INF/lib/spring-kafka-3.0.1.jar
> BOOT-INF/lib/kafka-clients-3.3.1.jar

If I connect intellij-debugger to the running jar-file and put a breakpoint in any of my own code I can do a `Class.forName("org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule")` successfully.
But if I try to put the break point in `javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java)` where the error occures I get `ClassNotFoundException`. Im not skilled enough with regards to class-loading to be able to decide why this happens.

Ive looked at suggested solutions in [unable to find LoginModule class: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule when the springboot app is run on docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66261214/unable-to-find-loginmodule-class-org-apache-kafka-common-security-plain-plainlo) and [Spring Kafka MSK : Unable to find LoginModule class:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74888635/spring-kafka-msk-unable-to-find-loginmodule-class)
but none of them seem to make any difference for me.

Ive been been pulling my hair now on this for a couple of days and would very much appreciate some help.
Please let me know if there is any additional information that I can provide

Regards

**EDIT**:
No one that has any suggestions? What puzzles me is how there can be difference in running

```
./gradlew clean build && java -jar build/lib/fat.jar
```

vs

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

Comment: Consider updating your code with https://stackoverflow.com/a/72697441/4778022, and if this pattern does not work then update the code in the question to reflect your new code.  This may help those looking to help you futhur.

Comment: Good point - I did try the, slightly contradictory, suggestions in both posts linked but removed the them since they didn not work.